# TypeError in MessagesController#create_message no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am integrating SMS API in Rails app. While taking numbers from user table I am getting the error as:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  app/models/message.rb:16:in `+'
  app/models/message.rb:16:in `sms_message'
```

This is my `message.rb`

```
def sms_message
    require "rubygems"
    require "net/https"
    require "uri"
    require "json"
    uname = "demo@gmail.com"
    hash = "54030737b105dsds7777 "
    numbers = numbers
    message = body
    sender = "TXTLCL" 
    requested_url = 'http://api.textlocal.in/send/?' + "username=" + uname + "&hash=" + hash + "&numbers=" + numbers + "&message=" + body + "&sender=" + sender
    uri = URI.parse(requested_url)
    http = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    res = http.request(request)
    response = JSON.parse(res.body)
    puts (response)
end

def message_number
  numbers = Student.new do |u|
    u.phone1 = numbers
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has a nice method called to_query.
First, build a params hash like this:

```
params = {username: uname, hash: hash, numbers: numbers, message: body, sender: sender}
```

Then, just call `"http://api.textlocal.in/send/?#{params.to_query}"`

`params.to_query` will take care of nil values.

But, this is just a nice way of writing the code. If the values are nil, you will still get the same error. Better is to add some validations before making the API call. Also, make sure if you are sending the exact keys that the API expects.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `numbers` or `body` as `nil`

To avoid this you can either convert those values to string or use interpolation

**Convert to string**

```
numbers = numbers.to_s
message = body.to_s # Use message instead of body while joining using +
requested_url = 
  'http://api.textlocal.in/send/?' + "username=" + uname + "&hash=" + hash + 
  "&numbers=" + numbers + "&message=" + message + "&sender=" + sender
```

**Use Interpolation**

```
requested_url = 
  "http://api.textlocal.in/send/?username=#{uname}&hash=#{hash}&numbers=#{numbers}&message=#{message}&sender=#{sender}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still I am getting **No recipients specified**      as :                                                                                              {"errors"=>[{"code"=>4, "message"=>"No recipients specified"}], "status"=>"failure"}

Comment: ah. that maybe because of nil values in url

Comment: you can `return` if the values are `nil`